# Angular - number form-control not validating as expected in Reactive Form

Tags: angular

I have this reactive form in Angular-12:

Component:

```js
createVehicle() {
  this.createForm = this.fb.group({
    fuel_tank_capacity: ['', [Validators.minLength(0), Validators.maxLength(200000)]],
  });
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.createVehicle();
}


createValidate() {
  if (!this.createForm.valid) {
    this.createForm.markAllAsTouched();
    return;
  }
}

createValidate() {
  if (!this.createForm.valid) {
    this.createForm.markAllAsTouched();
    return;
  }
}

get fc() {
  return this.createForm.controls;
};

submitForm() {
  this.isSubmitted = true;

  // stop here if form is invalid
  if (this.createForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }
  this.isLoading = true;
}
```

HTML;

```html
<form [formGroup]="createForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">

  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="fuel_tank_capacity">Fuel Tank Capacity (Litres):</label>
      <input type="number" formControlName="fuel_tank_capacity" placeholder="e.g. 300" class="form-control" min="0" max="200000" />
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="isSubmitted || (fc.fuel_tank_capacity.touched && fc.fuel_tank_capacity.invalid)">
      <div *ngIf="fc.fuel_tank_capacity.hasError('minlength')">
        <div class="text-danger">
          Fuel Tank Capacity cannot be less than 0 characters!
        </div>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="fc.fuel_tank_capacity.hasError('maxlength')">
        <div class="text-danger">
          Fuel Tank Capacity cannot be more than 2000000 characters!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="isLoading" class="btn btn-success" (click)="createValidate()">
                  <span *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
                  <i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I don't want the max value for fuel to go beyond 200000. This works on the vertical scroll. But when the user types something like **800000000** which is beyond 200000, and then move to another form control, it doesn't show the user that  **Fuel Tank Capacity cannot be more than 2000000 characters!**

How do I make this happen, even before the form is submitted?

Thanks

Comment: Does the console show anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Validators.max() instead of Validators.maxLength():

```js
this.createForm = this.fb.group({
    fuel_tank_capacity: ['', [Validators.min(0), Validators.max(200000)]],
});
```